# can't visit the action url on submitting form in laravel

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I am new to laravel.So this question may seem stupid but i am requesting a simple explanation in this regard.

I am new to laravel.I have created  a form.blade page to make a simple form .
I have a `RESTful controller` named `taskController.php` and i want to visit the `create() method` inside it .And from `create() method` i want to visit the `welcom.blade.php` page

```
  public function create()
    {
        //
        return View::make('welcome');
    }
```

For this parpose i have created a folder called `task` inside `resource/views` folder and inside the task folder i created  php file called `task.create.blade.php`.But when i submit the form i am not redirected to `taks.create` page.Getting some kind of error .

**How i can solve this problem and can redirect my application to task.create page on form submit ?**

form.blade.php

```
<h1>login form</h1>
   {!!Form::open(array('url'=>'task.create')) !!}

   {!!Form::label('email','Email Address')!!}
   {!!Form::text('email')!!}

    {!!Form::label('comment','Comment')!!}</br>
    {!!Form::textarea('comment','',array('placeholder'=>'put your comment here'))!!}

    {!!Form::checkbox('agree','yes',false)!!}
    {!!Form::label('agree','i agree with your terms and condition')!!}

    {!!Form::submit('submit')!!}
    {!!Form::close()!!}
```

route.php:

```
Route::post('/',taskController);
```

Comment: what is your route and what error you are getting?

Comment: Your task folder should be under resources/views

Comment: task folder is under resource/views

Comment: yea, Route::post method takes a string in format of 'controller@method'. You can do Route::controller or Route::resource for more implicit routing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Route**

```
Route::get('/',function(){
   return view('task/create');
})
Route::post('task/create','taskController@postCreate');
```

**taskController**
you should have this function

```
public function postCreate(){
   return view('welcome');
}
```

**View**
rename **task.create.blade.php** to **create.blade.php**

and add this line on **create.blade.php** file

```
{!! Form::hidden('_token',csrf_token()) !!}
```

and change this line

```
{!!Form::open(array('url'=>'task.create')) !!}
```

to

```
{!!Form::open(array('url'=>'task/create')) !!}
```

Comment: i always ended up inside index method..can't trigger the create() method :(

Comment: you created same function and routes as i asked or  you are trying something else?

Comment: i wanted to visit the create page directly from url. i tried this but always ended up inside the index () method Route::resource('task/create','taskController');

Comment: Try this one    Route::resource('task','taskController');

Comment: it redirects me to index() also as expected ,,, shouldn't i have to specify that i want the create() method to trigger...it's confusing

Comment: you are trying to use route resource and trying to submit form , which is   post method. so laravel automatically map it to store function(post) of taskcontroller. In order to send to create method , using route resource, you have to specify method after url. so you have to   replace {!!Form::open(array('url'=>'task/create')) !!} to {!!Form::open(array('url'=>'task/create','method'=>'get')) !!}.. you can also use route controller . For more information https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers